# PHPMailer working on localhost and not on staging, same config on both

Tags: php, docker, phpmailer, staging

I have a problem with phpmailer, everything is fine on my localhost, I get the mail back from my php application but when I use the same docker container on my staging environment, the phpmailer return success but I get no mail in my mailbox anymore :/

Here is some code :

```
//create an instance of PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host='ssl0.ovh.net'; 
$mail->Port = 465;    
$mail->Username = 'hey@thomasmorice.com';    
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';        
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Priority = 3; 
$mail->CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"; //ISO-8859-1 _ utf-8
$mail->setFrom('admin@thomasmorice.com');
$mail->AddAddress('hey@thomasmorice.com');

$mail->Subject='New mail';
$mail->Body =  "
  Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n
  Mail : " . $_POST['inputEmail'] . "\r\n
  Message: \r\n\r\n" . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);
$mail->SmtpClose();

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

$data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Here is the response I have on the server :

```
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO staging.thomasmorice.com
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: aGD76QHRob21hc21efmljZSaajb20=
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: QnhuNnJDWW5lOp8A
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<admin@thomasmorice.com>
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<t.morice4@gmail.com>
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 9 Aug 2017 07:37:48 +0000
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: t.morice4@gmail.com
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: admin@thomasmorice.com
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: New mail
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID:<066e8c3f0b442dca0c4fdabf896a0d1b@staging.thomasmorice.com>
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:       Name: thomas test mail
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:       Mail : sendermail@testmail.com
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:       Message:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: test mail
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2017-08-09 07:37:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
{"success":true,"message":"Thanks! We have received your message."}
```

I'm really stuck on this because I have exactly the same configuration on localhost and on the server docker container) 
Maybe it is because of my MX in the dns ? I'm lost do someone have a clue ?

Thanks a lot for your help

-- edit

Something weird after some research, using [this website](https://mxtoolbox.com) to test the MX lookup with the MX tool, I see that when I run the test with my local server : thomasmorice.dev, I get a dns record found :/ how can this be since this is my local server :/ 
Doing the same with staging.thomasmorice.com, I get a DNS error.. In my opinion this should be the other way around.. I'm really confused

Comment: Not sure if it matters but you are closing your SMTP connection before sending the email? `$mail->SmtpClose();`

Comment: Oh yeh that is weird I have to admit :/
I've removed this line.. but still have the same issue :/

Comment: You could try reading [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). If you set `SMTPDebug = 2` you'll see what the server is saying. Also, you need to update PHPMailer.

Comment: @ThomasT. Just going to ask the obvious.. You've checked your junk/spam folders? The fact you get the success message means PHPMailer hasn't failed and deems it sent. Since you've changed your environment maybe the new environment needs some spf/dkim records?

Comment: @Matt thank you for your suggestion, yes I checked the spam folder and unfortunately it is not there either.
I don't really know about spf/dkim records stuff :/ maybe I should read more about this because that doesn't mean anything to me lol

Comment: @ThomasT. I'll take a further look tonight when I get home and compare versus what I've been using to see if anything stands out. Good luck though!

Comment: @Matt that's nice of you thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently I gave it a last try, and it looks like it is working right now. I hate when it happened.. 
Like, I haven't changed anything recently that is related to this mail function or anything :/ but it just work.. 
So consider it fixed :D Thanks for your help everyone !

Comment: glad to see it's fixed. Mark yourself as answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

function sendMail($name,$maill,$message)
{
    $url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $msg = wordwrap($message,70);
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xxx';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->From = $maill;
    $sujet=$name;

    $mail->addAddress($maill);               // Name is optional
    $mail->Subject = $sujet;
    //$mail->Body    = ;
     $message='

     </html>
      ';

    $mail->MsgHTML(
    $message
    );

    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}

$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Try this. It may work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work..
Actually, we don't even use the `$url` variable after setting it so I don't know how this should work tbh :/

Comment: what version of phpMailer you use ? anyway  try to change this                              $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; or may be the firewall of the host block the sending of emails

Comment: Don't post random code without explaining *why* it addresses the OP's question, which in this case it does not.

Comment: but this code works on my server , i just tried to gives him the code maybe it works for him too